# How to speed up fancybox2 external urls load time?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2, load-time

I'm using `fancybox2` to display external urls on my site as iframes.

sometimes it just takes too long for the page to be displayed.

**Q:** Is there a way to speed up the external url load time?

Answer (score 0):

An iFrame is just a standard page being loaded. If you need to speed these up, you will need to apply the same tricks as for any other page, namely:

- Gzip compression on the remote server
- Caching on the remote server
- Reducing the size of the page being loaded
- Reducing the number of requests being made

Alternatively, you could preload the page, so the iframe is loaded with the current page, instead of waiting for the fancybox to be ready.

Comment: I don't have control over the external urls.
I was thinking maybe there is some fancybox property I could use to speed things up.

Comment: I doubt so, since it's just loading an iFrame. You could always preload the iframe to speed things up, but this adds to the initial page load time.

Comment: I just got rid of it and open external urls in new tab.

Comment: That sounds like the more appropriate solution. Is it for a portfolio?